# Stop sending preflight requests from axios.post

Tags: spring, reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security, react-hooks

I have my micro-service developed using spring-boot and spring security and frontend is designed on react-hooks.
Now, while I am send some data to my micro-service using axios.post method, it send CORS preflight method i.e. options method because axios by default send content-type as application/json and application.json leads to send options request to server before any other request.

I have tried sending my request with different headers and content types as 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' also I have used @cross-origin(*) at my server end.

```
const config = {
                    headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                }

            const response = await axios.post(ps.user_ms_url+ps.user_login,
                {
                    username:values.email,
                    password:values.password
                    // headers:{'tokenvalue':'token'}

                },
                config);
```

I expect my browser to send only post request to the server, for that I am ready to change my headers as well. 
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is expected to happen if you are requesting from different domain. Are you using create-react-app for your react app? there's a way to get a way with CORS using proxy and builtin create-react-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution for my query. As I mentioned above, our browser sends preflight request (means options request) before any other request if our request is not simple (here simple means: if request contains content-type : application/json or custom headers etc) and if we are sending this request to some other domain/ URL.

And our axios.post method carries content-type as application/json by default, that's why, my browser was sending multiple requests (means preflight request before any other request).

Now, I have changed my request content-type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded by sending data as params, as shown below:

```
     var params = new URLSearchParams();
                params.append('username', values.email);
                params.append('password', values.password);

            const response = await axios.post(ps.user_ms_url+ps.user_login,
                params);
```

And handling this request at backend using @ModelAttribute annotation (Spring-boot). So, keeping request simple can stop preflight requests.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid CORS preflight request by proxying the request. Add this in your webpack development config

```
  devServer: {
    port: process.env.PORT || 3000,
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http:localhost:8080',
        pathRewrite: { '^/api': '' },
        changeOrigin: true,
      },
    },
  }
```

This means your request to `/api/users` will forwarded to `http://localhost:8080/users`.

If you are using create-react-app. just add `"proxy": "http://localhost:8080"` to your package.json. Check more info [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development#docsNav)

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. And you are right as I am requesting from different domain but I didn't understand your answer. Like, how i will be able to stop preflight methods by proxing the request as I am already able to hit the URL.

Comment: are you using webpack?

Comment: no, I'm not using webpack but yes, I m using create-react-app for my react app

Comment: as i said add this to your package.json `"proxy": "http://localhost:8080"` then add '/api' prefix to your requests to backend

Comment: I applied proxy in my package.json but it didn't work for me. And can you please tell how will it work to stop options request?

Comment: as I said add prefix '/api' to your requests. so instead of `http://localhost:8080/login` 
(i dont know what the value of this `ps.user_ms_url+ps.user_login`) you replace the url with `/api/login` this means that your webpack-dev-server is proxying the request to your backend

Comment: I understand that but as in my case I am runnning my front end at http://localhost:3000 and backend at http://localhost:8090/someurl/someotherurl/login.... So, as per your solution, I should add a line "proxy": "http://localhost:8090" in my package.json and I will hit url with "/someurl/sopmeotherurl/login".... Am I right?

Comment: here it is step by step. 1) add this to package.json `"proxy": "http://localhost:8090` . 2) repalce this `/someurl/sopmeotherurl/login` with this`/api/someurl/sopmeotherurl/login`

Comment: Yes, I have applied exact code as you said but now it is hitting the URL as http://localhost:3000/api/someurl/sopmeotherurl/login

Comment: yes that's actually what we want. webpack-dev-server should proxy your request to your backend. check your backend logs if it hits your server. what is actually the route for the login in your backend?

Comment: No, It is enable to hit my backend server and Route to my backend login service is : http://localhost:8090/someurl/someotherurl/login and what exactly my browser hitting is: http:/localhost:3000/api/someurl/someotherurl/login

Comment: correction- not able*   (it is not able to hit server)

Comment: I see my mistake. please take a look at this sandbox. `https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-sutherland-o7gql`
There's a file setupProxy.js copy it under your src and edit the target. it should work if you are using react-scripts@2.0.0 or higher

Comment: I did as you said and your proxy is working properly. Now, my browser is hitting localhost:3000 instead of server address which is localhost:8090 and I am able to login successfully. That's good, proxying is implemented as you said but still my browser is sending 3 requests on login click, it is sending preflight request as well. And I am looking for solution to avoid multiple requests on single click and one more thing when I enter right credentials then it sends only 1 request and if I enter wrong credentials it sends 3 requests including preflight request...

Comment: you should use /api/ prefix on all your request. i don't think the request with preflight is proxied.

Comment: let me know if it works and please accept my answer. thanks!

Comment: your proxy is implemented successfully but it is not able to stop preflight requests as I said in my question. I don't want proxified requests if it is sending OPTIONS request before POST request.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be server side CORS issue. You have to allow domains to access resources by providing correct response headers.

You can look at adding CORS headers in spring boot. Refer to this [link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/)

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: Yes, I have already provided access to * at my server end as I have provided: @CrossOrigin("*") annotation at my URL mapping which allows all the request domains to hit URL